# Problems with Neo4j Browser in Chrome

Tags: neo4j

I have problems with Neo4j Browser, everything works correctly in Firefox but not in Chrome

When I run the query frame results not shown

I don´t know if these problems occur after Chrome updates

I tried with versions 2.0.1 and 2.0.2 Neo4j

Comment: Which OS and which Chrome version?

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 OS and I guess the latest version of Chrome, updates are autom

Comment: Have the same issue on OsX Yosemite 10.10.3 & Chrome 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit)